# How do you create a global style for multiple buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

I have a project with multiple buttons, most of which all need to be the same size and colour. I am wondering if it is possible to apply a global style to all the buttons rather than having a bunch of repeated style code for each button.

Comment: Look at [`ttk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html). It is part of the `tkinter` library. It stands for *Tk themed widgets*.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the different buttons and apply the same configuration to them, like in this piece of code where I had to present different social media apps and used Frames for each. You can just list your buttons in the tuple and configure them in the loop.

```
for frame in (facebook, twitter, pinterest, whatsapp, instagram, snapchat, linkedin, Statistiques, acceuil):
    frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')
```

So for example:

```
for button in (button1, button2, button3):
    button.config(...)
```